# Can the "&"-symbol (ampersand) be used in Japanese to connect two language names?

Tags: translation, usage, nuances, english-to-japanese, loanwords

For example, is this correct and commonly understood by Japanese-readers:

> "日本語 & 英語"

which should represent "Japanese & English" and denote a bilingual edition of a certain text document?

I understand that the most correct way to connect the two language names is:

> 日本語と英語

where "と" does not precisely mean "and", but rather "with", as stated in [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/usage-and-reading-of-the-ampersand).

Brief background:

I'm designing the layout for bilingual info-brochures for a university-project and Japanese is among the given languages.
On the cover page I want to place the contained languages, as a subtitle of sorts, for example:

```
ランダムなタイトル

日本語 & 英語
```

As the ampersand makes a good design-element in the latin languages, it would be favourable beeing able to use it for the Japanese versions as well.

So the question is really *how well or bad* it the ampersand perceived and if it's acceptable to be written / printed in a semi-formal context (i.e. university-conference). Or does it look too non-native / unprofessional?

Comment: In sufficiently informal contexts, modern Japanese speakers might do all kinds of things like this. I've even seen English conjunctions like `in` and `with` loaned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter "&" is indeed used in the sense of "and" (to join) the two words as you say.

It is not that this symbol is particularly impolite or non-native.

However, if you use it at the "university" you are talking about, it might be considered a bit "impolite" by the professor or teacher.

Rather than being impolite, this symbol is rather informal and is used for messages between friends, not for school documents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will definitely go with "と" based on your answer. 
This is going to be read by guests from all around the globe and is not an academic exercise.

Comment: nice! Thank you!